# Delphi DBgrid Wrap Word Content

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Is it possible to Word Wrap DBgrid Cell (height) in Delphi (xe)  ?
I have a dbgrid with multiple columns with a fixed Column width and some columuns has up to 100char and I need them to fit the appropriate Cell without changing the Column width.

Any clue how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use ownerdraw, and paint the text `OnDrawCelll`

Comment: @kobik, but you will need to adjust row height as well.

Comment: Surely this has been done thousands of times already https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+wrap+dbgrid

Comment: @kobik: TDbGrid does not have OnDrawCell. It does have OnDrawColumnCell

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to make it ownerdraw, and in the OnDrawCell event put the code to fill in the cells:

```
procedure TForm4.Grid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);  
begin
Grid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+1, Rect.Top+1, WrapText(Grid1.Cells[ACol,ARow], 40));
end;
```